# So Bane was actually helping Batman all along?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

I came across [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/2n3o1p/nolans_batman_bane_broke_the_bat_to_save_gotham/) post about *The Dark Knight Rises* after it was shared by somebody on Facebook.

It says that Bane secretly acted against the League of Shadows and wanted to redeem Gotham and help Batman to accomplish that. All he did to Gotham and Bruce was in order to call Batman back into action, help him overcome his personal issues and lure the League of Shadows into an attack for Batman to defeat them once and for all and effectively secure him as a symbol for Gotham's protection. So it basically says that the story as it unfolded was all in Bane's intentions.

**Question:** Is Bane really a good person trying to resurrect Gotham as suggested in the above post, or is there any solid argument against this theory?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Bane is **VERY** much a villain and **does not** help Batman in the film. Christopher Nolan envisaged and wrote him as villain. His actions throughout are cold blooded and cruel. Despite showing care for Talia, he is merciless in his destruction of all others, murdering at will and threatening to slaughter an entire city.

Much of the theory is centred on the idea that Bane *strengthened* Batman by leading him on a journey to make him a tougher, more powerful hero and thus was the true 'dark knight'. However, this involves completely misreading many scenes and the countless actions of Bane which prove otherwise.

**(Very) Long Answer***

I will try and tackle the key *themes* of the theory, by posting it from the source in Italics. I will then draw on a variety of source materials to show my disagreement.

The theory begins:

> *Bane is, in many ways, a bizarro sort of Batman. He is extremely intelligent, he's iron willed, he's physically powerful, and he's got
>   a justice agenda of his own that got him kicked out of the League of
>   Shadows.*

This statement begins with a correct assertion. Bane **is** a twisted version of Batman, as [Christopher Nolan intended](http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/the-playlist-interview-christopher-nolan-talks-writing-process-in-dark-knight-rises-the-idea-of-batman-as-sociopath-finding-his-darth-vader-villain-20121206?page=2):

> The really interesting thing about Bane is, he's massively strong but
>   he's also extremely intelligent, and his past very much mirrors Bruce
>   Wayne’s in interesting ways, from his training and with the League of
>   Shadows background. Bane represents the the wrong path of Bruce Wayne
>   almost back to “Batman Begins.” So Bane is the return of that danger.
>   The wrong side for Bruce Wayne.

However, this is where theory begins to go astray. It states his *justice agenda* led to him being kicked out of the League of Shadows. This simply isn't true. Bane was imprisoned in the Pit, along with Ra's al Ghul's wife and daughter (Talia). The other prisoners killed the wife, but Bane intervened to save Talia and help her escape. She found the League of Shadows and returned with them to free Bane, who was inducted into their ranks. He left because he was a constant reminder of the place where Ra's al Ghul's wife had died - so Ra's had him excommunicated from the group. There was no alternative notion of justice that contributed to this. Throughout the entire film, his philosophy - to destroy Gotham, a city corrupt beyond redemption - is identical to Ra's' goals.

The theory continues:

> *First, he has to convince Bruce that Gotham needs Batman. Then, he needs to show Bruce that Batman is more than Bruce could ever be.
>   Finally, he needs to secure a victory for Batman over the League of
>   Shadows. He gets the League to go all in here. Talia seems to be the
>   last of the organization, so a victory for Batman doesn't just grant
>   Gotham a reprieve, it effectively destroys the League of Shadows. If
>   any of this can't be achieved, the League of Shadows wins, and Gotham
>   is destroyed.*

Bane's actions towards the beginning of the film are all designed to install Talia as the head of Wayne Enterprises, so she can gain access to the nuclear fusion core they had. When Batman confronted him and they fought, he crippled Batman and *told him* what his goals were:

> So, as I terrorize Gotham, I will feed it's people hope to poison
>   their souls. I will let you believe they can survive so that you can
>   watch them clamoring over each other to "stay in the sun". You could
>   watch me torture an entire city and then when you truly understand the
>   depth of your failure, we will fulfill Ra's Al Ghul's destiny. We will
>   destroy Gotham. ***And then when it is done and Gotham is ashes, then you
>   have my permission to die.***

There is no intention to save the city, or do anything positive for it - only to destroy it. Now, even if you were to argue (however ludicrously) that this was all a ploy to strengthen Batman, when they had their rematch, and Bane *was* overpowered, Talia stepped in to save the day and leave Batman in a heap. She left to ensure the thermonuclear bomb detonated, giving Bane strict instructions to ensure he died in the fire. Bane ignored this, as the script shows:

> Bane grabs Batman, throws him into the floor - checks the
>             rounds in the barrels.
>   **BANE** - You'll have to imagine the fire -
>   *He shuts the gun - jams it into Batman's face.*
>   We both know I need to kill you
>              now.
>             *He squeezes the trigger. BLAMMM! Bane is blasted across the
>             lobby by cannon fire.*
>             *Catwoman is there, on the Bat-Pod.*
>   **CATWOMAN** - The whole no-guns thing? I don't
>              feel as strongly about it as you
>              do.

The only reason Batman survived this was because Catwoman happened to arrive at the right time. Again, there is nothing to show he is in anyway helping Batman - just trying to destroy him. The only reason he allowed Batman to survive in the pit was, as shown above, out of a sadistic desire to let him see his city burn - and, interestingly, to echo the treatment *he himself had* when he was in the pit; a cruel, torturous wait for an inevitable end.

The theory then states:

> Batman tries to confront Bane and Bane teaches Bruce a very important
>   lesson: Bruce isn't immortal or unbreakable. Batman needs to be both
>   of those things.

Or to put it another way - he beats Batman up! Which is [completely canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Knightfall) and sets him up as a truly *physical* enemy, something that [Nolan also intended](http://screenrant.com/dark-knight-rises-christopher-nolan-interview-sandy-143443/):

> Bane, to me, is something
>   we haven’t dealt with in the [Batman] films. We wanted to do something
>   very different in this film. ***He’s a primarily physical villain, he’s a
>   classic movie monster in a way — but with a terrific brain.***

The theory then postulates:

> *So then there's the pit, and the quite literal rising.*

This is intended and is far more likely a reference to [The Lazarus Pits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_Pit) of the comic, something Nolan himself discussed on the DVD. Ra's al Ghul used them in the comics to *restore* himself - instead, Batman uses them here.

The theory then comments:

> *Batman and Bane fight. Batman wins this time with some help, and now
>   it's time to save Gotham. Catwoman is all "you've already given them
>   everything" and Batman is like "not everything. Not yet." and that is
>   so fucking key. Bruce had given Gotham his body, his wealth, and his
>   heart. But he hadn't given them Batman. Bruce Wayne, the angry kid
>   trying to avenge his parents, didn't come out of the Lazarus pit.
>   Batman did. All that Bruce has left in the world is Batman, and his
>   final act in the cowl is to give Batman to Gotham completely. Gotham
>   will forever have the symbol (and the crime fighter, if John Blake has
>   any luck.)*

Catwoman wanted him to give up because she was ruthless and selfish. This is true throughout the film. She would leave the millions of people to die. Bruce Wayne/Batman cannot do that. So he saves them. However, I'm not sure *why* that means he's suddenly *just Batman*. If that interpretation was true, why on earth would he *stop* being Batman immediately after saving the day. It's not as if there wasn't still crime to deal with.

As for the notion that he has given Gotham the Batman signal forever - he'd already done that. We see evidence of this throughout the film (e.g. the little boy doodling the Batman symbol on the bench). Many people in the city still belived in him.

The theory then finishes:

> *We're left with a Bruce Wayne who has moved beyond his parents,
>   Rachel, and Gotham. He had to give up Batman to do that. Gotham has
>   Batman, is safe from itself, and safe from the League.*

This effectively states that *because* Batman became stronger, Bane is the *true* dark knight and hero. That's just nonsense. If I were to walk home today and get beaten up by a thug, inspiring me to take fighting lessons which made me stronger and able to defend myself in future, has that original thug saved me or helped me? No! Of course not. They weren't doing good, they weren't a hero. They were a villain. Like Bane. On a much smaller scale.

To throw in a few final arguments, remember that Bane is perfectly content with the plan to detonate a device that will kill millions. He televises this fact and then, in front of the world, murders Dr. Pavel, the only person who could disarm the device. He also goes to the prison and instigates a full riot, all in the name of creating anarchy and allowing Gotham to burn. He murders countless people, setting explosions all across Gotham, including at the football stadium:

**Conclusion**

There is no *logical* way to look at Bane's actions as anything other than cold hearted and cruel. He was a villain, as Nolan intended. He slaughtered people willingly and, despite showing care for Talia, showed nothing but cruel hatred for the rest of the world. His actions were evil. He was just evil.

<sub>* I've edited this answer quite drastically to make it flow better. The original can be viewed (if desired) in the edit history of this answer.</sub>

Comment: Folks that's two down votes now. Can someone leave a comment explaining *why*? Do you disagree with my analysis? After the amount of effort it took to gather all this information, it would be good to get *some* information!

Comment: You could have been downvoted just because you took the time to spell it out and explain yourself along the way.  Short attention spans tend to bring out those who get angry at exposition.

Comment: @BonGart: I suppose. Thank you. I tried to keep it succinct, but it got longer and longer as I threw more and more evidence *against* the theory. It really just doesn't add up, in anyway. Perhaps I should edit it down a bit, or at least add a better summary.

Comment: @AndrewMartin one of the best and thorough answer I've seen in SE

Answer (score -2):

I find the argument perfect enough to justify Bane's actions and why he didn't kill Batman.

- That, and the fact that Bane didn't directly kill any good person by
  himself throughout the movie (AFAIK), correct me if I am wrong.
- And his kind act of saving the young Talia from the
  dungeon exemplifies that he was good in nature.
  Bane only killed the bad people: Dagett, Dr Pavlov, his own henchmen

Here is my perspective after reading the theory:

In TDKR, Batman is the white knight and Bane the Dark Knight!

In TDK, Nolan made Gotham believe Batman was the villain while he was the hero all along. Similarly in TDKR, Nolan made *us* believe Bane was the villain while he was the hero all along...

If this is true, Nolan deserves all the awards awarded on this planet for this movie. (I know a bit off topic, but had to say this) :)

Comment: Batman handed a loaded weapon to someone willing to use it.  That person proved they were willing to use it, and they did... and someone died at the muzzle end of that (those) guns.  A white knight would NEVER do that.  White knights do not break the rules.  They find a way to work within them.  So... I can't agree that Batman has ever been, or would ever be, a white knight.  That's my reason for the my downvote.

Comment: Which gun are you talking about? Batman has only one rule which he keeps till the end. In TDK even the white knight kills other people because injustice was done to him. In TDKR I do not recall Batman killing somebody. So in a way Batman is more a white knight than Dent...

Comment: Pretty sure he's referring to the moment Batman gave Catwoman the Batpod. There are high level weapons on that vehicle, and Catwoman would most definitely use them if she felt the need to. Batman wouldn't even gun down The Joker when he had a perfectly good chance. Could have gunned/mowed him down and ended everything right then and there.

Comment: I strongly disagree that a singular case of "altruism" (in the case of Talia) could possibly overshadow the countless, atrocious crimes he committed and otherwise facilitated.  Consider the deathcount of the football players, implied (and unshown) victims of the entire city crumbling, psychological trauma to an entire city held hostage, unspoken victims from crimes (committed by opportunists knowing it's a lawless city), and the sadism of breaking Batman's back and imprisoning him with a TV showing his hometown people suffering....

Comment: @hexparrot that is why he says he is _necessary_ evil. Bane doesn't commit any crime during the anarchy, he simply shows the existing angst and cruelty that was forcefully suppressed by the Dent Act. The way you portray him to be cruel, he would surely have all the policemen killed when they were underground. But he doesn't. And as mentioned in the post, all his actions were to reinvigorate the dormant Batman inside Bruce.

Comment: @MattD he gives the Batpod to Selina so that she can blast the blocked tunnel so that people can escape the city in the event of a catastrophe. His only rule is that he will not directly kill anybody, doesnt mean he doesnt want to kill the bad guys indirectly. This is why he _kills_ Raas Al Ghul. The argument that just because he handed a weapon to Selina disqualifies him as a white knight IMHO is a pretty lame argument. In Batman Begins, he gives one of his weapons to a _child_, which may or may not be abused, just saying...

Comment: "Bane doesn't commit any crime during the anarchy?"  I feel like you are being willfully blind. Planning to destroy the city with what is effectively a bomb, and threatening to kill people who attempt to leave the city may not have happened "during the anarchy", but still count as a behavior unambiguously villainous.

Comment: @AndrewMartin even though you have put forth a good argument against the theory, can you please explain Bane's certain actions which are contrary to your argument. For example, why does he not kill all the policemen when they were underground? He obviously knew their location as he forced them there and as you say he was cruel and cold blooded. Also, why does he not reveal the identity of Batman, and given that during that stage of the movie, people viewed Batman as a vigilante who killed their hero Dent, this would truly tarnish Bruce's reputation and kill him emotionally.

Comment: @hexparrot "Planning to destroy the city with what is effectively a bomb, and threatening to kill people who attempt to leave the city" was part of his plan to reinvigorate the dormant Batman inside Bruce. This is because Bane knows how much Bruce cares of Gotham and will go to the any extent to save it. And if he really wanted to kill all the people without any intention of making Batman a hero, why provide so much time to Batman in the pit so that he recovers from all his injuries and then comes to the rescue of Gotham?

Comment: ...because he wrongly didn't anticipate that a broken back could be healed while in a third-world hole, malnourished and without real medical attention. The sadist in him wanted batman to witness Gotham explode....  Er. I'll be checking out now; if you're truly in agreement that an iconic villain could be an ally, there's little use to arguing.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: TylerShads provides a good theory on the police officer's treatment [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/how-did-the-police-department-survive-and-why-were-they-allowed-to). Another argument is that Bane tried to *reverse* things, meaning the rich got poor, the righteous were judged, etc. The police were treated like criminals and confined. Of course that's just a theory - we don't *really* know. It seems likely though that this was just part of his sadism, similar to keeping Batman alive (so he could watch everything burn).

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Also, he may have been under instructions from Talia to keep everyone alive until the moment the bomb detonated. As for not revealing the identity of Batman, why would he? He didn't view Batman as a threat, easily overpowering him in their first meeting. Instead, he left him to rot and watch his city burn - again an act of reversal, with the hero becoming helpless. Ultimately though, even if we *accept* these all as *plot holes*, it totally overlooks the crimes he *without question* committed.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: He murdered all the football players (along with others around the city in the bridge bombing). He tried to murder Batman (in their second meeting). He tried to kill a whole city (which only Batman and Catwoman stopped). The theory provides **no** justifiable reason for *any* of this. It overlooks all the *glaring* contradictions the movie presents, instead focussing on a *few* contentious scenes to argue its point. It's a fascinating theory, but ultimately it just *doesn't* hold up in anyway against what Nolan presented (or what the comic books detail).